# Creating AWS S3 object life cycle using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, awss3transfermanager

Creating AWS S3 object life cycle using NodeJS.

I want to create S3 object life cycle via API using NodeJS. When I see the documentation, AWS provided only multiple object life cycle, with Java.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-set-lifecycle-configuration-intro.html

I also checked this url -

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getBucketLifecycle-property

**Genral Concern**

How to set multiple Transition with NodeJS like the way Java has ?

```
BucketLifecycleConfiguration.Rule rule2 = new BucketLifecycleConfiguration.Rule()
                .withId("Archive and then delete rule")
                .withFilter(new LifecycleFilter(new LifecycleTagPredicate(new Tag("archive", "true"))))
                .addTransition(new Transition().withDays(30).withStorageClass(StorageClass.StandardInfrequentAccess))
                .addTransition(new Transition().withDays(365).withStorageClass(StorageClass.Glacier))
                .withExpirationInDays(3650)
                .withStatus(BucketLifecycleConfiguration.ENABLED);
```

Followed by -
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-set-lifecycle-configuration-intro.html

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

we need to call `putBucketLifecycle` and pass `Rules` Array to `LifecycleConfiguration`. Similar to [CLI Example](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-lifecycle-configuration.html#examples)

```
s3.putBucketLifecycle(
  {
    Bucket: "sample-temp-bucket",
    LifecycleConfiguration: {
      Rules: [
        {
          Filter: {
            And: {
              Prefix: "myprefix",
              Tags: [
                {
                  Value: "mytagvalue1",
                  Key: "mytagkey1",
                },
                {
                  Value: "mytagvalue2",
                  Key: "mytagkey2",
                },
              ],
            },
          },
          Status: "Enabled",
          Expiration: {
            Days: 1,
          },
        },
        {
          Filter: {
            Prefix: "documents/",
          },
          Status: "Enabled",
          Transitions: [
            {
              Days: 365,
              StorageClass: "GLACIER",
            },
          ],
          Expiration: {
            Days: 3650,
          },
          ID: "ExampleRule",
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  (error, result) => {
    if (error) console.log("error", error);
    if (result) console.log("result", result);
  }
);
```

Comment: Glad I could help. If this answer has solved your question please consider upvoting and/or [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.